# How can we import module from another directory

Tags: python, import, relative-path, python-3.8

I have a project with a folder structure that looks like :-

```
.
├── custom_logger.py
├── dataframe_creation.py
├── helpers.py
├── __init__.py
├── ontology.py
├── ontologyV1.py
├── sample.py
├── Specialties.xlsx
└── tests
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── test_data
    │   └── SampleMetals.json
    └── test_ontology.py
```

I want to import modules like **dataframe_creation and OntologyV1** in test_ontology.py which is present in the **tests** folder.

```
import json
import sys
sys.path.insert(0,'/home/udit/Desktop/owl_ontology/owl_ontology/')
import unittest
import os, pathlib
from unittest.main import main
from owl_ontology.dataframe_creation import DataframeCreation
```

I used this sys.path.append function (as in the above snippet), but it still doesn't import the module instead give me an error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/home/udit/Desktop/Final_Ontology/owl_ontology/owl_ontology/tests/test_ontology.py", line 7, in <module>
    from owl_ontology.dataframe_creation import DataframeCreation ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'owl_ontology'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the full path, for example if the file is present in local disk D: use sys.path.insert(0,'D:/home/udit/Desktop/owl_ontology/owl_ontology/')